# Pick common elements from two dataframes of varying column length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare, row

These are my dataframes:

DF1

```
0 Animals   0
1 Octopus   Aquatic
2 Fish      Aquatic
3 Mouse     Land
4 Cat       Land
5 Dolphin   Aquatic
```

DF2

```
0  Animals  0
1  Cat      Land
2  Fish     Aquatic
3  Shark    Aquatic
```

How I would like my result dataframe:

```
0  Animals  0
1  Fish     Aquatic
2  Cat      Land
```

Since the order of common elements vary, merge() isn't applicable here. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: try : `pd.merge(df_1, df_2, on=["Animals", "0"])`

Comment: read [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra)